# What does it mean for a sequence of random variables to be independent and uniformly distributed?

Tags: probability, expectation

Assume that $Y_1, Y_2, ..., Y_{100}$, are the rounding errors made on one hundred items and that these are independent and uniformly distributed over the interval $[−50(\text{USD}), 50(\text{USD})]$.

By the distribution assumption made for each $Y_i$, $E(Y_i)=0$ for $i =1,2,...,100$

Why is $E(Y_i)=0$?

Comment: The expectation of uniform distribution on interval $[a,b]$ is $\frac12a+\frac12b$ (the point in the midst). As was to be *expected* right?

Answer (score 3):

No, not quite. What you have provided in the comments is the *density*. For simplicity, $Y_i = X$, and what you have given is 
$$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{b-a} = \frac{1}{100}.$$

Then to find the expectation, we follow the usual formula
$$E[X]  =\int_{-50}^{50} x\cdot f_X(x)\,dx = \int_{-50}^{50}x\cdot\frac{1}{100}\,dx = 0.$$

Somewhere along the way, you were probably given that for a random variable $X$, if it follows $\text{unif}[a,b]$, then
$$E[X] = \frac{a+b}{2}.$$

You can verify this. It also gives the same result, $E[X] = \frac{-50+50}{2} = 0$.

---

Addendum:
In the case that it follows a discrete uniform distribution, $P(X = k)$ for some $k$ in $[-50, \dotsc,50]$ is $\frac{1}{101}$. So using the usual formula for *discrete* cases, we have
$$\sum_{k = -50}^{50} kP(X=k) = 0.$$

You can verify that $E[X] = \frac{a+b}{2}$ for the discrete case too.

Comment: "density" comes in by continuous uniform distribution. In the question we are dealing with discrete distribution.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. But do the rounding errors have to be discrete? I haven't really thought it through, and from my experience discrete things are usually written $[a, \dotsc, b]$, but I know that doesn't always have to be the case.

Comment: "rounding" points in the direction of discrete. However, don't bother too much. This answer is helpful anyway.

Comment: @drhab Thanks. It wasn't too much trouble, so I added the discrete case.

Answer (score 3):

The values of the underlying amount variables $X_i$ may come from the most diverse sources: from items sold at integer dollar prices, from sales with 5ct or even 1 ct precision, or from currency conversions. It follows that the $X_i$ are for all purposes continuous real variables. Our investigator is inclined to throw the small change away, i.e., he will only deal with hundreds of dolloars, obtained by rounding. The rounding errors $Y_i$ in the question are then continuous real variables in the range $[-50,\>50]$. *Uniformly distributed* means that for any subinterval $[a,b]\subset[-50,\>50]$ the probability $P\bigl[Y_i\in[a,b]\bigr]$ is equal to the ratio ${b-a\over100}$, and *independently* means that even if you are told the true values of the first ninetynine $Y_i$, this gives you no hint whatsoever what the value of $Y_{100}$ could be. Whether these assumptions are justified in the case at hand is not discussed; they just form the base of the mathematical model.

Simple symmetry considerations should make it intuitively clear that $E(Y_i)=0$ in such a model.